# Performance issue with two full-text calls in one cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, full-text-search

I need to combine results of two full-text calls. Both returns separate within few seconds, but takes together minutes.

I removed all MATCH and other clauses to isolate the problem best.

If I call

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("nameIndex", 'some word') YIELD node as kw
RETURN count(kw)
```

or

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("article_fulltext", 'other word') YIELD node as a 
RETURN count(a)
```

both return in less than a second and shows about 500.000

But if I call

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("nameIndex", 'some word') YIELD node as kw
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("article_fulltext", 'other word') YIELD node
RETURN count(a), count(kw)
```

It takes minutes.

I tried to separate if but without an effect.

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("nameIndex", 'some word') YIELD node as kw
WITH kw , count(kw) as kwl
WITH kwl
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("article_fulltext", 'other word') YIELD node as a 
WITH kwl, a ,count(a) as al
RETURN kwl, al
```

How to tell neo4j that this calls are independent?

Comment: Why not using a `UNION` ?

Comment: There's usually not such a thing as independent parts of a Cypher query. Operations execute per row, so however many rows are returned from the first call, the next operation (the second call) will be executed for each of those rows. You'll want to either use a UNION or do your aggregations immediately after each CALL.

Comment: Also your count aggregations aren't going to be correct. Counts are with respect to the non-aggregation variables present with the aggregation (this is called the grouping key). So `kw, count(kw)` means you will have each `kw` entry on its own row, and a count of that single entry (1) for each of those rows. If you want the count of all `kw` across all rows, you either need to remove `kw`, or aggregate it so it won't be a grouping key.

Answer (score 3):

Since your first `CALL` returns 500K results, your second `CALL` is invoked 500K times. That is obviously not what you intended and very, very slow. And it and would also give you the wrong counts.

Use `WITH COUNT()` to reduce the number of results from the first `CALL` to just one.

For example, this should be much faster and also give you the correct counts:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("nameIndex", 'some word') YIELD node
WITH COUNT(node) AS kws
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("article_fulltext", 'other word') YIELD node
RETURN COUNT(node) AS ows, kws
```